# How to Insert OLE Data from VBA to MS Access Database OLE Data Column

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Below is the code to do the following

1. Initialize Variable for Connection and Recordset to MS Access Database
2. Pick the desired gif/jpg/png/bmp file from the desired folder
3. Copy the read binary data from image file to byteArr
4. Construct INSERT Query
5. Execute the insert query

But I am getting Automation Error. Looks like I am not able to make an apppropriate INSERT query with Image Data, Please help me in this

================================================================================

```
Private Sub CommandButton9_Click()

Dim cnPubs As ADODB.Connection

Dim rsPubs As ADODB.Recordset

Dim strSQL, strcon, Str1, strFile As String

Dim byteArr() As Byte

Dim Newarray()

Dim fileInt As Integer

Set cnPubs = New ADODB.Connection

Set rsPubs = New ADODB.Recordset

strcon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=C:\Users\10703906\Documents\Database41.accdb;" & "User Id=admin;Password="

cnPubs.Open strcon

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Picture files (*.jpg, *.png, *.gif, *.bmp)", "*.jpg,*.png,*.gif,*.bmp"
    .InitialFileName = "C:\Temp1\*.jpg"
    If .Show Then
        Image1.PictureAlignment = fmPictureAlignmentCenter
        Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(.SelectedItems(1))
        strFile = .SelectedItems(1)
            
        fileInt = FreeFile
        Open strFile For Binary Access Read As #fileInt
        ReDim byteArr(0 To 10)
        Get #fileInt, , byteArr
        Close #fileInt
    End If
        byteArr(0) = 39
        byteArr(8) = 44
        byteArr(9) = 39
        byteArr(10) = 41
End With

Str1 = CStr(byteArr)

Dim CarName, CarBrand, Str2, Str3, Str4 As String
Dim State As Integer
Dim closebracket As String
CarName = "Polo"
CarBrand = "Volkswagon"
State = 1

Str3 = String(1, 44) 'Comma
Str2 = String(1, 39) 'Single Quote
Str4 = String(1, 41) 'Closing bracket

Str1 = Str3 & Str1 & Str3 & Str4
                      
strSQL = "Insert Into Table4 (ID,Name,Company,Automatic,Image)  Values (" & 8 & Str3 & "'" & CarName & Str2 & "," & "'" & CarBrand & "'" & "," & State & Str1
rsPubs.Open strSQL, cnPubs, adOpenKeyset

rsPubs.Close
cnPubs.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Saving files in table uses up Access 2GB size limit. Why not keep files external and save path in text field? I haven't had much luck with OLEObject field and have only used Attachment field.

Comment: I was just trying the store the image data read into the OLEObject field, but it is not working. But if saving the filename in dababase and store the file somewhere, if that works, it is perfectly fine with me.